# Reading label text from .resx files in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, localization

I am trying to find a way of  looping through a *.resx* file that contains English words and replacing them with the translated equivalent.

I have used a `ResXResourceReader` to read the file, can anyone help please

Comment: Thank you for the posts. I have now built an app that loops over a .resx file and only replaces the text values from that file with the ones in my database.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly get the text by `specify key`

```
String Text = GetLocalResourceObject("yourkey").ToString();
```

Comment: I can loop over the file using the ResXResourceReader but i need to find a way of only reading the text values for label items and serialize the file with the new values

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify from which side do you want to do it? I mean, if it's just for a developer, that can see the code, you can do it easily changing the .resx files, but if you want to design an interface so a user can translate without seeing any code, then I'd do it with LINQ to XML. I can show you if u need examples but answer first.

Comment: At the moment I have a database full of English words and the translations for them in several other languages. What I need to do is to on a button click loop through the file and replace the text for labels in the file to the translation. I don't need to worry about producing the file, I already have generated it.